# Change Ruby Process Name in OSx

Tags: ruby, process, naming

I am trying to give my Ruby program a different name. I am running this on OSx with Ruby version 2.1.2-p95. I am looking in the **Activity Monitor** which I believe uses top, but I am not 100% sure.

I have tried `$0 = "My process name"`, `$0 = "My process name\0"`, `$PROGRAM_NAME = "My process name"`, `$0 = "my_process_name"`. None of which seem to do the trick.

I have also tried:

```
require "fiddle"
def set_process_name(name)
    Fiddle::Function.new(
        DL::Handle["prctl"], [
            Fiddle::TYPE_INT, Fiddle::TYPE_VOIDP,
            Fiddle::TYPE_LONG, Fiddle::TYPE_LONG,
            Fiddle::TYPE_LONG
        ], Fiddle::TYPE_INT
    ).call(15, name, 0, 0, 0)
end
set_process_name("My process name")
```

I would love to have a cross-platform way to do this, but I'm mainly after an OSx way right now.

---

Similar question without satisfactory answer:
[Change the ruby process name in top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450620/change-the-ruby-process-name-in-top)

Comment: Is specifically top/activity monitor output you want to change or the output from ps ?

Comment: I would like it to change in Activity Monitor as this is where most mac users will be looking.

Comment: Too bad, Process.setproctitle only seems to do ps

Comment: Yeah, I found that myself. I have been struggling with this for a bit unfortunately.

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution for this?  I found some issues that may be relevant at Thoughtbot's [gitsh](https://github.com/thoughtbot/gitsh/issues/41) and the [Ruby issue tracker](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10090)

Comment: I never found a solution for this :( I honestly have just been ignoring it. On windows you can do `START "My name" ruby.exe whatever.rb`, but I have no idea how to achieve this on unix :(

Answer (score 2):

I have not found a cross platform way to do it. The closest thing is using `Process.setproctitle` but on OSX it just works on the command line, not in the Activity Monitor app.

For OSX you will need bundling your script within an App and [set the process name on the Info.plist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201531/rename-app-process-name) file